# Notification Count not shown Badges in App Launcher Icon in Android Version 29 and 27

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I want to show unread messages count on my android app's launcher icon. It should be cleared only once the user read all messages. I have tried `setnumber()` in `NotificationCompat.Builder`. But it is not showing the notification count.

I executed my code in two android devices.

1. Real Android device - version is 29 (red dot appeared in app launcher when i generate notification)

   [image]
2. Android Emulator - version is 27 (nothing is shown)

   [image]

Notification Channel Creation:

```
private void createNotificationChannel(String notificationChannelId, String systemTrayNotificationName){

    Log.i("Tag","createNotificationChannel "+Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        CharSequence name = systemTrayNotificationName;
        String description = systemTrayNotificationName;
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(notificationChannelId, name,importance);
        notificationChannel.setDescription(description);
        notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
        notificationChannel.canShowBadge();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = getContext().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
}
```

Code to form notification

```
public void buildNotification(){

    createNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,SYSTEM_TRAY_NOTIFICATION_NAME);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Content Text")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setNumber(5)
            .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_NONE)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    // Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());

    // Issue the notification with notification manager.
    notificationManager.notify(200, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The number of notifications must be supported by the launcher you are using.
As far as I know, the pixel launcher typical of google phones and present by default as launcher3 of the emulators does not support the notification count exactly as it happens in your first case.
You could try with a third party launcher to see if the counting works but as just said this feature must be natively supported by the launcher.

Comment: Thanks,Can you please let me ,Where can i find the list of android devices supports "show count in app launcher"?